# Can there be Art without an Artist?

Tags: art, existence-of-god

I'm by far not an artist.

However my interpretation of Art is.

Man creates Art that is a depiction of the world we occupy. This depiction of Art is meant to convey some meaning that the artist has about the world that they wish to express to others by that Art.

It's arguable that before man there was no Art created by man.

However, man creates Art which includes a depiction of the natural world and it is qualified as Art by man.

So can you argue that before man, just what created the Art intrinsic in the natural world that man recognises and qualifies as Art?

Does all Art require an Artist?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150308/discussion-on-question-by-8mad0manc8-can-there-be-art-without-an-artist); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> Does all Art require an Artist?

Cheeky answer: **yes**.

Wiktionary [defines "art"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/art) as:

1. The conscious production or arrangement of sounds, colours, forms, movements, or other elements in a manner that affects the senses and emotions, usually specifically the production of the beautiful in a graphic or plastic medium.
2. The creative and emotional expression of mental imagery, such as visual, auditory, social, etc.
3. Skillful creative activity, usually with an aesthetic focus.

In general, the term "art" is defined as a *meaningful* expression. Randomness, on its own, does not create meaning. Even if someone uses random processes to create "art", the very act of selecting which results are worthwhile is a conscious act.

Whether the appearance of such meaning in nature suggests an Artist / Designer / God is another question!

Comment: If meaning eventually occurred and happened in the universe, that does not mean that the universe did not happen to occur meaning from its beginning ?

Comment: Not a "cheeky" answer, a valid and correct answer.

Comment: I'll also add, if your answer is no, not all Art requires Artist, from my interpretation is that you conclude the world is not art and therfore does not require an Artist, or that some art does not require an artist?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8, definitionally, "art" is meaningful. As was discussed in [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150308), that arguably means that randomness is not "art" until someone appreciates it, whereupon in a sense the observer *becomes* the artist. Whether "the world" is art in and of itself gets into the question of whether there is a capital-A Artist (i.e. "God"), which, as I said, is another question!

Comment: @Matthew I have posted a comment in the chat thanks for the link. I have seen another member of the community post about paraidollia in response to your answer. But I would also like to make a comment here. It can appear that life is random however there are patterns in nature such. We think in determinism allows free will but that freewill creates patterns and reason, to behaviour and this behaviour can be reflected in Art. It's not just physical rules that create those patterns.